# ActionScript 3 - How do I get my String to convert to a Number?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, numbers, type-conversion

I have a Budget field (called txtBudget) where I want users to enter a number value.
I then want to store what they entered as a variable (totalBudget) so that I can perform calculations based on it later.

My problem right now is that when I go to a different frame, and then return to the frame with the code, the text field displays "NaN".  I can't work out why, and it's driving me mental.

On frame 1 I say:

```
var totalBudget:Number = 0;
```

Then on frame 14 I tried:

```
 onBudgChange(null);

 txtBudget.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, updateBudget);

 function updateBudget(event:Event):void {
      totalBudget = Number(txtBudget);
 } 

 function onBudgChange(event:Event):void {
      txtBudget.text = totalBudget.toString();
 }
```

And when that didn't work I looked around and saw a post that said my text field wasn't a string, and that I needed a variable to convert it.  So I tried this (with no luck):

```
 onBudgChange(null);
 var budgetBridge = String(txtBudget);

 txtBudget.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, updateBudget);

 function updateBudget(event:Event):void {
      totalBudget = parseFloat(budgetBridge);
 }

 function onBudgChange(event:Event):void {
      txtBudget.text = String(totalBudget);
 }
```

I've been pulling my hair out, so any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Right, your textfield isn't a string, it's a textfield. However there's no need for an intermediate variable, all you have to do is using the `.text` property for reading the value:

```
function updateBudget(event:Event):void {
    totalBudget = parseFloat(txtBudget.text);
}
```

Comment: @Koru.Chico Please check his answer if it works.  Mark it as correct.